# Prevent parent click from firing if a specific child is click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to prevent my parent click method to fire if the user clicks on a specific child element.

Example html:

```
<div data-type="parent_holder" style="width:500px; height:500px;">
   <div data-type="child_holder" style="width:50px; height:50px; position:absolute;">
      click
   </div>
</div>
```

Example js:

I use jquery on in my js because I attach the element dynamically to a sortable list.

```
$( "#sortable" ).on( "click", "[data-type=parent_holder]", function() {
   alert('parent');
});

$( "#sortable" ).on( "click", "[data-type=child_holder]", function() {
   alert('child');
});
```

So what I want is, when a user clicks on the parent_holder it should alert parent, but if the user clicks on the child_holder it should alert child, and not alert parent.

I have searched stackoverflow and I have tried many of the suggestions, like :not(), bubbling, stopPropagation(), but I can't seem to get the right result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like event propagation is happening in your case,
just avoid that by using `event.stopPropagation()`

Try,

```
$( "#sortable" ).on( "click", "[data-type=child_holder]", function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   alert('child');
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/243SL/)

Comment: Thank it worked - actually I had seen the answer another place on stackoverflow, but I had used it wrong, so it helped that you made an example:-)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

or

```
return false;
```

in child click handler to prevent event propagation from parent events.

Comment: "return false" is not same as "e.stopPropagation()".  "return false" is same as "e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation()";

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you still need the click event to bubble from child element, you could filter instead the target inside parent click handler:

```
$( "#sortable" ).on( "click", "[data-type=parent_holder]", function(e) {
   if(!$(e.target).is('[data-type=parent_holder]')) return;
    alert('parent');
});
```

### --DEMO--